# Where does .net core docker container host the application?

Tags: .net, docker

We can host the .net core application in local machine on IIS/ngnix. Since Docker container uses underlying OS, where does the container host the application? Where is the code written to instruct the docker container to host on a particular server? Also, if we want to change configuration of the server e.g. IIS app pool settings, how to do it in case application is hosted on container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core web applications are capable of self hosting. So when you start a docker container, generally it just runs "dotnet xxx.dll".

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows containers, you can run IIS in the container and host your app there.

IIS is not available on Linux. ASP.NET has a self-contained web-server called Kestrel that it uses on Linux. Kestrel also runs on Windows.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-6.0